# Unable to deploy my Shiny App with shinyapps.io

Tags: r, deployment, shiny, shinyapps

Thanks in advance for your support about the following issue. I want to deploy my shiny app on shinyapps.io.
It runs perfectly using R-Studio, but when I'm trying to use shinyapps.io it returns a lot of erros that I can't fix at all. I'm using the next documents:

```
abrev_mes.csv
app.R
BDD_SIAF_2014_122019_02012020.sav
catalogo_cantones.xlsx
catalogo_delitos.xlsx
catalogo_region.xlsx
mes20142041.xlsx
trimestre20142041.xlsx
```

They are located at the root with no subdirectory folders whatsoever.

Can somebody help me with this issue? I don't know what else should I present to you in order to understand what the issue could be. The following are the errors that shinyapps.io returns:

```
An error has occurred
The application failed to start (exited with code 1).

Warning in readLines(file, warn = FALSE) :
 entrada inválida encontrada en la conexión de entrada '/srv/connect/apps/dashboard-fiscalia/app.R'
Error in parse(file, keep.source = FALSE, srcfile = src, encoding = enc) : 
 carácter multibyte inválido en la linea 122

Possible missing comma at:
443:    for (i in 1:which(grepl(input$periodo_x, vfecha_anio))) {
              ^
Possible missing comma at:
443:    for (i in 1:which(grepl(input$periodo_x, vfecha_anio))) {
                 ^
Possible missing comma at:
589:                   for (i in 1:15) {
                             ^
Possible missing comma at:
589:                   for (i in 1:15) {
                                ^
Possible missing comma at:
685:                   for (i in 1:15) {
                             ^
Possible missing comma at:
685:                   for (i in 1:15) {
                                ^
Possible missing comma at:
848:      } else if (req(input$periodo_tipo_st)== "Trimestral") {
                ^
Possible missing comma at:
900:                   for (i in 1:15) {
                             ^
Possible missing comma at:
900:                   for (i in 1:15) {
                                ^
Error in value[[3L]](cond) : 
 invalid multibyte string at '<fa>mero <64>e denuncias" = n,'
Calls: local ... tryCatch -> tryCatchList -> tryCatchOne -> <Anonymous>
Ejecución interrumpida
```

Comment: Did you precise any "fileEncoding" or "encoding" parameter when reading your file ?

Comment: I tried using this: Sys.setenv(LANG = "es")
But it did nothing. Also, I tried this: Sys.getlocale("LC_ALL=es_ES.UTF-8") but this one not even run.